# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error causing my map page not to load.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null.

var a = aLink.indexOf('/');

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. Obviously `aLink` is null.

Comment: So what's your question then? Are you asking how to fix it or what's the cause? Note if there are any `<a>` tags without `href` then you will get that error.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out and had to do with the order I was calling the script and it loading on the page with locations that was also calling a different script.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. In your page, you have a few tags like this one: `<a class='doPrettySearch btn corePrettyStyle' data-bind='click:locationSearch'>Go</a`, that have no `href` attribute. Still, you try to fetch the href attribute of *all* `<a>` tags, which will obviously produce and error.

Answer (score 0):

You can take care of unwanted exception using

```
try{
       if(statusmsg!=null && statusmsg.indexOf("pass") >= 0)               {
    {   return false; }
}
catch(err) {
        alert('Error :='+err.message);
}
```